# Setting API key in gvisMap

Tags: r, google-maps, googlevis

I'm trying to create a map to display in a website using the R library googleVis and the function gvisMap. I can generate the chart locally, but once I put it in a website, it gives an error [related to a missing api key](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#no-api-keys).

I searched about this issue and found [a similar problem](https://github.com/mages/googleVis/issues/66), but no solution. 
As far as I can understand, it is related to the fact that the call to the API uses a function (google loader) that may be deprecated and doesn't allow a reference to the API key. But I have no idea how to deal with it.

Here's a minimal reproducible example:

```
example <- structure(list(id = c(1497L, 1509L, 1583L, 5572L, 7361L, 8102L, 
                  8584L, 8734L, 9593L, 9614L), LatLong = c("-22.0267575:-44.3184877", 
                                                           "-22.6966783:-49.4322738", "-10.713746:-62.2545373", "-11.1369864:-42.1125701", 
                                                           "-9.9167727:-37.2763875", "-13.5779092:-39.2167652", "-5.7867453:-35.202613", 
                                                           "-22.017958:-44.5125127", "-4.8522095:-39.5748619", "-13.0786111:-39.0011556"
                  )), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                              -10L), .Names = c("id", "LatLong"))

library(googleVis)

mapa_tdp <- gvisMap(example, "LatLong" ,
                options=list(showTip=TRUE, 
                             showLine=TRUE, 
                             enableScrollWheel=TRUE,
                             mapType='terrain', 
                             useMapTypeControl=TRUE))

plot(mapa_tdp)
```

If, however, I save the htlm output and paste it in a website, it gives the mentioned error.

```
zz <- file(description="html_chart_mapa_obras.txt", open="w", encoding="UTF-8")  # open an output file connection 
cat(mapa_tdp$html$chart, file="html_chart_mapa_obras.txt")
close(zz)
```

And here's my session info:

```
R version 3.3.1 (2016-06-21)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)
```

Comment: my [googleway](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/googleway/index.html) package allows you to plot a Google map with the API key. You can use the CRAN release version, or the [development version](https://github.com/SymbolixAU/googleway/blob/master/NEWS.md) has quite a few new features.

Comment: I tried you package, but I don't know how to generate HTML code to publish on my website. I don't want to use it within a Shiny app.

Comment: have you tried `htmlwidgets::saveWidget()` ? However, be aware that I've had some [issues with using this](https://github.com/SymbolixAU/googleway/issues/79) that I haven't resolved yet.